# Porting @optional selectors in protocols to Java interfaces

Tags: java, interface, porting, objective-c-protocol

So, let's say you have this:

```
if ([foo respondsToSelector:@selector(bar:)]) {
   [foo bar:abc];
} else {
   [qux mux:abc];
}
```

And both `bar:` and `mux:` have side effects.

How would you port that to Java, where there is no such things as @optional members in an protocol (interface)?

I can think of three ways:

1. The C way: add a method to the interface that returns a bitfield representing which methods are implemented and valid.
2. The COM way: modify the interface so that all methods return a result code and check for E_NOTIMPL.  Use out params for return values.
3. The (what I imagine is the) Java way: mark each interface method as throwing UnsupportedOperationException and catch them to check for unimplemented methods.

Did I miss any other compelling choices?  Assuming this code is not frequently called so we don't need to optimize for performance, I'm thinking 3 is the best way as it is enforcable.  Are there arguments for the alternatives?

Comment: Another possibility to consider (though I don't know if it's a good one):  If the number of methods is small, you could have separate interfaces for each optional method.  Then for a given object `foo` you could check `foo instanceof BarMethodInterface`.  If true, then cast to that interface and call its method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the thing that you describe as "the Java way" is actually an anti-way: there should be no catching of `RuntimeException` subclasses in the regular flow of your program, because they signal programming errors.

A better way would be to split the protocol into smaller parts: all required methods would end up in a single interface, and the optional methods would be in their own tiny interfaces. Now you can test your objects with `instanceof` to determine if an optional interface and its implied method are implemented.

Here is an example:

```
@protocol MyProtocol
@optional
    -(void)method1;
    -(void)method2;
@required
    -(void)method3;
    -(void)method4;
    -(void)method5;
@end

interface IMyProtocol {
    void method3();
    void method4();
    void method5();
}

interface IMyProtocolMethod1 {
    void method1();
}

interface IMyProtocolMethod2 {
    void method2();
}

class MyProtocolImplWithMethod2 implements IMyProtocol, IMyProtocolMethod2 {
    public void method2() {
    }
    public void method3() {
    }
    public void method4() {
    }
    public void method5() {
    }
}
```

Then you can write this check:

```
if (obj instanceof IMyProtocolMethod2) {
    ((IMyProtocolMethod2)obj).method2();
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  This would imply I'd have to pass around `Object`s instead of `MyInterface`s.  But this is exactly the sort of alternative approach I hadn't thought of I am interested in considering.  But what you say is correct: this design is a programming error that I'd like to refactor to make the whole question academic.  :)

Comment: @jeffamaphone Why, you can keep passing `MyInterface`s around, so that you could invoke required methods "for free" (i.e. without a cast). As far as a "programming error" goes, it is idiomatic in Java to use runtime exceptions to signal programming errors (null pointer exceptions, failed argument checks, cast exceptions, not implemented method exceptions, out of range exceptions, and so on). It is OK to catch checked exceptions, such as I/O, SQL, communication exceptions, and so on.

Comment: Well, all the methods are optional.

Comment: @jeffamaphone In the worst case, you can create one interface per method, and use `Object` to pass instances around. If you can group some of your optional methods together (by observing that some methods are always implemented together) you'd be able to reduce the number of interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

MonoTouch has a well-established solution to exactly your problem: making code that's designed for Objective-C feel fairly comfortable in an OO VM language.

They solve it by having a base class that marks all required methods as `abstract`, and leaving optional methods unmarked (or, more precisely, marked as `virtual` in C#, but Java doesn't need that). It's explicitly designed around compile-time enforcement of required methods while still allowing for optional ones.

More detail: http://docs.xamarin.com/index.php?title=ios/tutorials/Events%2C_Protocols_and_Delegates#Protocols_Deep_Dive

Comment: But how do you write code that checks at runtime to see if the version your calling is the empty virtual method or an actual derived implementation?

Comment: Reflection. I'll try to craft an example.

Comment: I had a feeling you were going to say that.  Don't worry about the example.

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, the Java way would be to avoid such situation at all. Usually Java programmers go extra mile (and use many established patterns) not to break polymorphism - so switching on type would be considered a bad practice.

The simplest solution and a direct translation of @optional would be to use instanceof and have the optional methods inside an interface extanding the required methods:

```
interface MyProtocol {
   void required1();
   void required2();
}

interface MyProtocolWithOptional extends MyProtocol {
   void optional1();
   void optional2();
}
```

and then:

```
public static void test(MyProtocol mp) {
   mp.required1();
   if (mp instanceof MyProtocolWithOptional) {
       ((MyProtocolWithOptional)mp).optional1();
   }
}
```

If you have a lot of interfaces and your application is extensible at runtime, you could use a solution like capability pattern (http://java.dzone.com/print/4771) , where each object can be queried for available interfaces (which is a bit like COM, and a bit not like with COM). You begin with something like:

```
interface ThingWithCapabilities<T> {
    T interfaceFor(Class<T> inteface)
}
```

ThingWithCapabilities is the base interface extended by all others. And then use it at runtime:

```
public static void test(ThingWithCapabilities mp) {
    if (mp.interfaceFor(MyProtocolWithOptions.class) != null) {
        mp.interfaceFor(MyProtocolWithOptions.class).optional1();
    }
}
```

The nice thing is that the casting is gone. The nicer thing is that you don't tie the lifecycle of MyProtocolWithOptions instance to the lifecycle of the ThingWithCapabilities (eg. you can have a single instance of MyProtocolWithOptions catering for many ThingWithCapabilities instances; on the other hand, you can just return this if you happen to implement MyProtocolWithOptions). If you combine it with the null object pattern (where you have a statless instance of MyProtocolWithOptions that does nothing and is returned by each ThingWithCapabilities that does not have the MyProtocolWithOptions capability instead of null), you can get an even nicer code:

```
public static void test(ThingWithCapabilities mp) {
    mp.interfaceFor(MyProtocolWithOptions.class).optional1();
}
```

Unless you are writing something big, this approach is probably to complex. I just mentioned it, because it is interesting (and I have used it successfully on some pet projects).

Comment: I agree, I would like to avoid needing to do this completely.  And I have added this to the list of things to fix in an upcoming refactor.  But I found the question in and of itself to be worth pursuing.